# raid0 with operating system from single drive

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, raid-0

I just bought the msi ghost 003 laptop, which supports raid0 with with two drives. It came with a customized windows 8.1 operating system preinstalled. The problem is that its installed on a single drive. I'd like to utilize the raid0 support with two drives. It didn't come with a windows 8.1 disk or anything, just utilities disk. Is there a way I could copy all the data on the one drive to two drives using raid0?

To restate the problem. I have one drive with the os. I'd like to copy that data to two drives using raid0 so I can run the operating system from both those drives using raid0 or striping. I have another computer I'd be able to hook the two drives up to if that would be how to do it. Anybody know how I can do that?

Comment: Do you have a good backup strategy? RAID0 is simply two or more disks' capacities combined and offers no redundancy. I.e. One or more disks fail and you'll lose the lot as it has no way of rebuilding. RAID0 = D1 + D2 + Dn... seen as one logical storage area. RAID1 will give you hardware failure redundancy but you don't get extra disk space from your multiple disks. I.e. RAID1 = D1 mirrored to D2. RAID5 gives you space and redundancy for one disk failure but requires at least 3 disks.

Comment: yeah, i just want the performance raid0 offers. i usually reinstall my system every couple months anyway. I do understand what raid is, i'm only looking for performance.

Comment: You could install the new disk and - using Win 8 storage spaces functionality - add the new disk to your Win 8 install without reinstalling or copying

Comment: If i understand what your saying, thats exactly what i'm looking for. so i can just install the disk, and windows 8 has some kind of functionality to "combine" that disk with the one currently running windows 8?

Comment: Yes. Look up Storage Spaces. Not sure on versions required but I think all Win 8's do it...